# How to find last modified subfolder?

Tags: vbscript

I have a log folder that contains subfolders with log files of a build server.
Each time a build is triggered, a new subfolder is created with log files.
I want to find the path to the last created subfolder within the main build folder.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the FileSystemObject.

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MainFolder = fs.GetFolder("C:\Docs")
For Each fldr In MainFolder.SubFolders
    ''As per comment
    If fldr.DateLastModified > LastDate Or IsEmpty(LastDate) Then
        LastFolder = fldr.Name
        LastDate = fldr.DateLastModified
    End If
Next

MsgBox LastFolder
```