# How to get latest created subfolder

Tags: vbscript

In VB Script how to get latest sub-folder?

C:\Automation\QTP\Branch\Test Results\UPDATE_CUSTOMER 017_QTP\EB\20140508_1210_PM

In the above path I know up to "C:\Automation\QTP\Branch\Test Results\UPDATE_CUSTOMER 017_QTP\EB\20140508_", for every few minutes new folder will be created with different time as suffix like 20140508_1213_PM. So here how to get the latest folder got created under "C:\Automation\QTP\Branch\Test Results\UPDATE_CUSTOMER 017_QTP\EB\"

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4100081/603855 (first link unter Related!).

Comment: I got the answer for my question....

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set RootFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Automation\QTP\Branch\Test Results\UPDATE_CUSTOMER 017_QTP\EB")
For Each folder In RootFolder.SubFolders
    If folder.DateLastModified > LastDate Or IsEmpty(LastDate) Then
        LatestFolder = folder.Name
    End If
Next

WScript.echo LatestFolder

Comment: Where did the `LastDate = fldr/folder.DateLastModified` go? BTW: Did you upvote Remou's answer?